# How can I animate multiple radial gradients clockwise in a div?

Tags: javascript, css, web, frontend

I have the following codes:

**HTML**

```
<header class="hero">
  <section class="hero-text-container">
    <!--Content Here-->
  </section>

  <figure class="hero-figure">
    <!--Image Here-->
  </figure>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero {
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse 30% 100% at -4% 5%, #ce0058, transparent),
    radial-gradient(ellipse 100% 75% at 0% 0%, #cf4520, #460702, transparent),
    radial-gradient(ellipse 100% 100% at 100% 100%, black, black);

  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: justify;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;

  animation-name: colors-circulating;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
}
```

I deleted HTML code for shortening but it's implemented.

#### The CSS above is styling the  div with a black bg, and a 2 radial gradients of brick brown & hot pink. The gradients are located originally near the div's top left corner. See the full Implementation here:[Hero Banner of a website I'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQBL7.png)

### I want to animate the gradients to move clockwise from the top left => top right => bottom right => bottom left, so I wrote this code:

```
@keyframes colors-circulating {
  0%, 100% {
    background: radial-gradient(
        ellipse 30% 100% at -4% 5%,
        #ce0058,
        transparent
      ),
      radial-gradient(
        ellipse 100% 75% at 0% 0%,
        #cf4520,
        #460702 60%,
        transparent
      ),
      radial-gradient(ellipse 100% 100% at 100% 100%, black, black);
  }

  25% {
    background: radial-gradient(
        ellipse 30% 100% at 96% 5%,
        #ce0058,
        transparent
      ),
      radial-gradient(
        ellipse 100% 75% at 100% 0%,
        #cf4520,
        #460702 60%,
        transparent
      ),
      radial-gradient(ellipse 100% 100% at 100% 100%, black, black);
  }

  50% {
    background-image: radial-gradient(
        ellipse 30% 100% at 96% 105%,
        #ce0058,
        transparent
      ),
      radial-gradient(
        ellipse 100% 75% at 100% 100%,
        #cf4520,
        #460702 60%,
        transparent
      ),
      radial-gradient(ellipse 100% 100% at 100% 100%, black, black);
  }

  75% {
    background-image: radial-gradient(
        ellipse 30% 100% at -4% 105%,
        #ce0058,
        transparent
      ),
      radial-gradient(
        ellipse 100% 75% at 0% 100%,
        #cf4520,
        #460702 60%,
        transparent
      ),
      radial-gradient(ellipse 100% 100% at 100% 100%, black, black);
  }
  }
```

Now the problem is, this code is showing 4 sharp images without any smooth animation. How can I make the gradients move smoothly?

I saw the following solutions, but unfortunately none of them worked for me:

- [How to apply multiple css radial gradients to a single element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677429/how-to-apply-multiple-css-radial-gradients-to-a-single-element)
- [Animate a div background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269514/animate-a-div-background-image)
- [How to animate a radial-gradient using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57218443/how-to-animate-a-radial-gradient-using-css)
- [CSS animation not smooth with radial-gradient background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305422/css-animation-not-smooth-with-radial-gradient-background)
- [CSS-Animation with two radial gradients moving/spinning inside the clipped mask png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75182822/css-animation-with-two-radial-gradients-moving-spinning-inside-the-clipped-mask)

I know maybe my implementation is not so correct, I am really doing my best.

How can I implement the idea I explained above using CSS &/or vanilla JS?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve this is to stack two elements in a positioned container, one with your content and one as the background. Absolutely position the two contained so they stack and set the fron to a higher z-index with a transparent background. Oversize the background and offset it so the corners won't show, hide overflow with the container, then just rotate the entire background element.

```css
.contain {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contain>div {
  position: absolute;
}

div.front {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  border: solid 2px blue;
}

div.rear {
  width: 200px;
  left: -50px;
  top: -50px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(at bottom left, blue, red);
  border: red solid 2px;
  animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="front">With all your text etc</div>
  <div class="rear"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7om4vcpg/

Comment: Keep in mind thatmy hero banner is not square / circular. Roratting it will set the background out of its bounds

Comment: That's why I mentioned over-sizing the background div and cropping it with the container. Adjustments can be made to the parameters of the radial gradient to reorient the colors so they can be kept in frame/to your liking.